# Mutex Blocks UI Thread

Tags: c#, wpf, block, mutex, ui-thread

I have background thread in my application which uses mutex like this:

```
  void bgWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
      MyMutex.MuImageLock.WaitOne();                
      foreach (var file in ImageFiles)
      {
          SyncFileToLocalImage(file.FileNameNoPath);
      }
       MyMutex.MuImageLock.ReleaseMutex();          
    }
```

and it takes around 2-3 minutes to sync. Now there is one more background thread in my application which do same thing just to make sure.

My Issue is, before I start my 2nd thread I want to check that if mutex is available or not. If it's not available that means another thread is running, then I do not need to start this new thread. so to check that I a using below code.

But using below code, `WaitOne` method blocks my UI thread until that previous thread does not release Mutex.

```
if (MyMutex.MuImageLock.WaitOne())
{
   getPRImages();
   MyMutex.MuImageLock.ReleaseMutex();
}
```

I dont want to block my current UI thread I just want to see that mutex is available or not. How would I do that?

Comment: You can use the [`WaitOne`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189907(v=vs.110).aspx) overload that accepts a timeout. Set the timeout to a millisecond and see if it is able to grab it based on the return value.

Comment: you could wait on a background thread if you want to avoid blocking. what version of .net are you using? there are different approaches (more convenient with every other version) depending on what you are using.

Comment: I am using VS 2013. I want to know if there is any event available which gets fired when mutex got released.

Answer (score 1):

In your code example, you don't seem to be using any features of `BackgroundWorker` except the background thread itself. So the right way to approach this would be to simply keep a flag and use `Task.Run()` to start the background process:

```
private bool _isRunning;

private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (_isRunning)
    {
        return;
    }

    _isRunning = true;
    await Task.Run(() => SyncAllFiles());
    _isRunning = false;

    // Populate ListBox here
}

private void SyncAllFiles()
{
    foreach (var file in ImageFiles)
    {
        SyncFileToLocalImage(file.FileNameNoPath);
    }
}
```

Note: in the above, I assume there is some UI button that causes the synchronization to begin. Unfortunately, your question doesn't include a complete enough code example to understand the context. Presumably, if not a button, you can adapt the above to suit your specific scenario.

Even if you were reporting progress and just happened to leave that out of your question's code example, you can still do the above. Just also use the [`Progress<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193692(v=vs.110).aspx) class, passing an instance of that to the `SyncAllFiles()` method and calling the `IProgress<T>.Report()` method to actually report the progress. This will work the same way as the `BackgroundWorker.ProgressChanged` event, in that the event handler will be invoked on the UI thread (as long as you create the `Progress<T>` object on the UI thread).

Note that even better than the above would be to simply disable the button or other UI element that would allow the user to start the operation again, re-enabling it only when it's completed.

Finally: I don't think there's a practical way to use the `Mutex` class (you are not specific in your post, but I assume you are using `System.Threading.Mutex`). Depending on the mutex to coordinate the operation and the UI thread seems like you're just asking for hard-to-solve race conditions. E.g. what if you get two click events on your button in a row, where the second is processed before the background thread can get started and acquire the mutex? That's just one of many possible ways it could go wrong.

The above proposed solution, by virtue of managing the state entirely in a single thread, will ensure that all race conditions are addressed directly.

Comment: I think it is worth pointing out that `mutex` is a form of blocking thread synchronization mechanism. This means that you can easily block the UI thread, which defeats the point of multithreading (on a client app) in the first place.